# basic maths calculations in c#

Tags: c#, math

so the snippet of code is me trying to increase a number by a percentage and I can't work out what I have done wrong as it keeps just giving me the number I'm trying to increase back. I am very new to programming in c# so please don't have a go at me but some help would be appreciated. (piNo stands for percentage increase by the way)

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number you want to increase");
            int piNo_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter the percentage you want to increase by");
            int piNo_2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int calc_1;

            calc_1 = piNo_2 + 100;

            int calc_2 = calc_1 / 100;

            int ans = calc_2 * piNo_1;

            Console.WriteLine(ans);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is the user wanted to increase by 50 % are they entering in 50 or .5?

Comment: Are you getting an error? what is the problem you encountering?

Comment: @DavidLee they are entering 50

Comment: Not 100% sure this is what you are looking for since I don't really understand what you want but try changing the variable types from 'int' to 'float'. Right now you can't have decimals, so you problem might be that all of your input gets rounded out.

Comment: Try the following, `(float)((piNo_2/100 + 1) * piNo_1)`, inside your `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `ans`

Comment: Thank you @LasseJacobs that fixed it.

Comment: thanks as well @davidLee but it turns out I just needed to make my ints, floats